# Pyodbc error after upgrading python from 3.8 to 3.11

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyodbc, python-3.11, sqlalchemy-access

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd, pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

def connStrMDBV2(fname):
    driver = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
    connection_string = (fr"{driver};DBQ={fname};ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;")
    connection_uri = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
    engine = create_engine(connection_uri)
    return engine

fname = fr'C:\Users\asd\Desktop\test11\mytest.mdb'
connStrMDBV2(fname)
```

I get the error:

```
raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc
```

I have checked all the packages are already installed and I am not using virtual environment. It used to work on Python 3.8 and I am getting error after upgrading to Python 3.11

Comment: When you do `pip list` does "sqlalchemy-access" appear in the output?

Comment: yes this package resolved it